# How can I add a background color and change the background colors for this logo I had created for me?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, background

The logo that I want to add a background to experiment with different background colors is the one on the artboard.

Here is a link to it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o9BEsZzCWdXOPojwrxUQnXrui03cpoVy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you familiar with Adobe Illustrator? That is merely a standard illustrator file. Are you asking how to use Illustrator? Have you attempted anything yet? Is so, what?

Comment: Google shows the logo via your link. After seeing it I suggest you do some searches with word "rectangle" and learn from Illustrator's manual how to draw a rectangle with solid color fill and how to arrange a shape behind anothers.

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE**. Please look around [tour] to get a sense of who we are as a community, and what we're about. Look at [ask] and [answer] questions, to learn how to frame acceptable queries and what to expect of replies and answers; please also look at [help/behavior] to understand our community's internal behavioural expectations. You will get far better responses and be less likely to get close votes if you can clearly show two major things in your question: 1) you've access and rights to the native file without an issue with your original designer; 2) what *you've* tried so far.

Comment: I do have access to all the native files and have full rights of the designs of the person who designed it. I did try to click on the background, to export it as a png file. And that didn't help. I also googled it and tried some things I read from different blog posts I read. However, after reading the very helpful comments here, I used the rectangle tool to draw a rectangle on top of it. Then I changed the rectangle to black. And then I used Arrange to send the rectangle to the back and it worked GREAT. Thank you all for the help!!